# Array.reduce() on an array of objects -- getting back strings of single letters

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I'm working to understand Array.reduce() in JavaScript. I have an array of objects that I'm trying to apply .reduce() to, but I'm getting back an array of single letter strings.

Goal:

```
["Stuff", "necklace", "ring", "bracelet"]
```

Current Array of Objects

```
const productArray =
[
    {
        id: 1,
        productTitle: "Necklace"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        productTitle: "Ring"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        productTitle: "Bracelet"
    }
]
```

Function call

```
const newStuff = productArray.reduce(function(a, currentValue) {
    return [...a, ...currentValue.productTitle];
}, ["Stuff"])
```

Actual result:
[image: weirdArray]

What do I need to do to specify that I don't want "productTitle" broken down into single-letter strings? I have been looking for resources regarding .reduce() on an array of objects but I haven't found anything very helpful. Any pointers?

Comment: Don't post images, post your code as a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 5):

To [concatenate an array and value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals) when using spread to create a new array, you spread the previous array to the new array, and add the new item without spreading it.

```js
const productArray = [{"id":1,"productTitle":"Necklace"},{"id":2,"productTitle":"Ring"},{"id":3,"productTitle":"Bracelet"}];

const newStuff = productArray.reduce((a, currentValue) => 
  [...a, currentValue.productTitle], []);

console.log(newStuff);
```

In this case, it's better to use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const productArray = [{"id":1,"productTitle":"Necklace"},{"id":2,"productTitle":"Ring"},{"id":3,"productTitle":"Bracelet"}];

const newStuff = productArray.map((currentValue) => currentValue.productTitle);

console.log(newStuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not spread the title, pass it as it is:

```
const newStuff = productArray.reduce(function(a, currentValue) {
  return [...a, currentValue.productTitle];
}, ["Stuff"]);
```

`...currentValue.productTitle` spreads into an array of individual letters, you only want to spread `a` variable, the aggregate here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a string is iterable, because the [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) is implemented and returns an array of single characters, if using [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

> **Spread syntax** allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.

```js
console.log([...'foo']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of spread in this case is unnecessary and inefficient as it creates a new accumulator array from the previous one on every iteration. You can remove spread (and fix your issue) and use *concat* instead to keep it as a one-liner.

However, since you're just adding one new value on each iteration, you should use *push*. It requires one more line of code but is likely more efficient than using *concat*.

```js
var productArray = [{id: 1,productTitle: "Necklace"},
                    {id: 2,productTitle: "Ring"},
                    {id: 3,productTitle: "Bracelet"}
];

// Using concat
var newStuff = productArray.reduce((acc, value) =>
  acc.concat(value.productTitle),
["Stuff"]);

console.log(newStuff);

// Using push
var newStuff = productArray.reduce((acc, value) => {
  acc.push(value.productTitle);
  return acc;
}, ["Stuff"]);

console.log(newStuff);
```

Comment: The text suggests `push`, but the code is using `concat`.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have pointed out why your code is wrong.  But I do want to also note that what you're doing is already covered by `Array.prototype.concat`:

```js
const productArray = [{"id":1,"productTitle":"Necklace"},{"id":2,"productTitle":"Ring"},{"id":3,"productTitle":"Bracelet"}];

const newStuff = productArray.reduce((a, val) => a.concat(val.productTitle), ['Struff']);
console.log(newStuff);
```

(And of course, as another answer has mentioned, this sounds more like a use for `map` than `reduce`, which might not matter since you're using this to learn `reduce`.)